# FORM on a SQL Query APEX

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am working in Oracle APEX 4.2. I have created Form on Table, Tabular Form and Form on Table with Report. I have tried a lot to create form on a SQL Query but i can't.

I have two Question related of Form on a SQL Query !

First i  want to make Form on SQL Query on Two Tables i-e `

```
Patient_Registration
```

> `Pat_Id(Pk),Name,Address,Gender ,Age,Contact`

and `Patient_Charges`

> P_Ch_Id(Pk),Patient_Id(Fk),P_Doc_Charges,P_Extra_Charges

Second is that if the from is made then we will be able to make insertions on two tables in one form  ?

Comment: What is your question? "I can't" is not enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think * I understand your question.

Create a view with your SQL query and then add a Before Insert trigger which does the necessary DML.

Check out some of the sample apps for ideas in this respect.